# Room. Один ко многим

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Собственно нужно что бы в MonthlyBudget

```
@Entity(tableName = "monthly_budget")
data class MonthlyBudget(@ColumnInfo(name = "budget_for_month")var budgetForMonth: Int,
                         @ColumnInfo(name = "date" ) var date: Date = Date()) {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
}
```

было поле с List

```
@Entity(tableName = "purchase")
data class Purchase(@ColumnInfo(name = "name") var purchaseName: String,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "cost") var purchaseCost: Int,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "monthly_budget_id") var monthlyBudgetId:Long,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var purchaseDate: Date = Date()) {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
}
```

Руководствуясь [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424148/6107009) создал третий класс MonthlyBudgetAndPurchase

```
data class MonthlyBudgetAndPurchases(
    @Embedded
    var monthlyBudget: MonthlyBudget,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id",entityColumn = "monthly_budget_id",entity = Purchase::class)
    var purchases:List<Purchase>

)
```

а в DAO вызываю так

```
@Dao
interface BudgetDAO {
@Query("SELECT * FROM monthly_budget")
fun queryAllMonthlyBudget(): LiveData<List<MonthlyBudgetAndPurchases>>
}
```

но только получаю

> MonthlyBudgetAndPurchases.java:4: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, реализовал как в статье, работает. Скажите, пожалуста, мне по прежнему нужен 3 класс что бы объединить эти 2 для удобного доступа? Если да то зачем вообще эта связь нужна?

Comment: Я сам Room не пользуюсь, но насколько могу судить, все делается через анотацию @ForeignKey. Третья таблица нужна только для связи Many to many, в чистом SQL так же реализуется, а Room это всего лишь враппер над SQLite. Связь нужна, чтобы можно было сделать выборку по одному многих с ней связанных. Узнать больше о SQL и понимать что происходит вам поможет книга Л.Бейли "Изучаем SQL", если вы собираетесь работать с реляционной БД и плохо представляете, как это делается, то надо ее прочитать обязательно.

Comment: @pavlofff Да я сделал все через эту аннотацию но при получении объектов из бд там нету нужного поля с покупками

Comment: Опишите проблемуподробно, отредактировав вопрос, как именно делали (код), что получается в итоге , какая структура БД и тд. По такому комментарию никто ничего определенного вам не скажет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему благодаря комментарию к вопросу, там была [ссылки](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a).
В итоге получилось такие Entity:

Purchase

```
@Entity(tableName = "purchase",
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = MonthlyBudget::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("monthly_budget_id"),
            onDelete = CASCADE)))
data class Purchase(@ColumnInfo(name = "name") var purchaseName: String,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "cost") var purchaseCost: Int,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "monthly_budget_id") var monthlyBudgetId:Long ,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var purchaseDate: Long = Date().time) {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
}
```

MonthlyBudget

```
 @Entity(tableName = "monthly_budget")
data class MonthlyBudget(@ColumnInfo(name = "budget_for_month") var budgetForMonth: Int,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "date" ) var date: Date = Date() {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
}
```